# Validate empty body request of PUT, POST method in JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm curious if there is an annotation/filter/interceptor capability in JAX-RS to detect if PUT or POST method contains an empty body.

Currently I have method that, if request has empty body, possibly throws NPE.

```
@PUT
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/update/{id}")
public Response updateCustomer(@PathParam("id") final String customerIdStr, final CustomerJson customer) {
    // if request body is empty -> customer == null
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

I can check `customer` for **null** . But since I have plenty of such methods, it's better to have filter to do such validation.

Please!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use Bean Validation, using an `@NotNull` annotation on your `CustomerJson` method parameter ?

Comment: Yes. It is returning short stacktrace string without ability to declare ExceptionMapper for it.

Comment: Mmmh, why can't you register an ExceptionMapper for it ? What class of Exception do you have ?

Comment: Well this is NPE. I don't want to catch NPE. The salt is to predict this NPE from empty body and make sure it is fixed before runtime. Other NPEs should be thrown in able to detect them.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong. You should have a MethodValidationConstraintException, not an NPE (see for example on  http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/30/resteasy-bean-validation-using-hibernate-validator-provider/)

Comment: Sorry but I use Resteasy 3.* - so MethodValidationConstraintException deprecated. Finally I've got helpful example here http://frankruenagel.blogspot.ru/2013/09/resteasy-30-with-hibernate-validator-5.html - it really works

Answer (score 1):

Interceptors read the HTTP body and I dont find a way to send the body for further processing. But you can do this by Servlet Filter and HTTP servlet request wrapper,

```
public class EmptyCheckFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    if (req.getMethod().equals("POST") || req.getMethod().equals("PUT")) {
      boolean dirty = false;
      HttpRequestWrapper wrapper = new MyHTTPRequestWrapper(req);
      try {
    // check body is empty by wrapper.getBody() and set dirty = true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
      if (dirty) {
        res.sendError(400, "Invalid input");
      } else
        chain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
    } else
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
  }
}

public class MyHTTPRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

  private final String body;

  public MyHTTPRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    super(request);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
      InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
      if (inputStream != null) {
        if (request.getCharacterEncoding() != null)
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, request.getCharacterEncoding()));
        else
          bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
          stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
      } else {
        stringBuilder.append("");
      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw ex;
    } finally {
      if (bufferedReader != null) {
        try {
          bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          throw ex;
        }
      }
    }
    body = stringBuilder.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        body.getBytes());
    ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
      public int read() throws IOException {
        return byteArrayInputStream.read();
      }
    };
    return servletInputStream;
  }

  @Override
  public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
  }

  public String getBody() {
    return this.body;
  }
}
```